Columns matching in Excel
I have four columns of data. Column A,B & D,E. A&B columns are one set and D&E columns are another set. Both have account number and amount. Both has same account numbers and amounts but they are in different order. I want to know, if Account number 10000 has 50000 in first set, then same account has 50000 or not in second set. Like way for all accounts are matching like first set.


You can try something like this using VLOOKUP() & IF()


=IF(VLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$B$7,2,0)=E3,"Matching","Not Matching")


And If you have access to MS365 then using MAP() function to spill for the whole array:
=MAP(D3:D7,E3:E7,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(VLOOKUP(x,A3:B7,2,0)=y,"Matching","Not Matching")))


